# C - make #define 'return' a value

Tags: c

Lets say I have define like this:

```
#define CrWinDef(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)\
{\
    HWND thw=CreateWindowEx(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l);\
    SendMessage(thw, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), (LPARAM)true);\
}
```

Now in my code I'd like to use variable 'thw'.
Using just

```
CrWinDef(...);
```

works.

However if add return thw; to my define and try to use same value in code it won't compile.

```
#define CrWinDef(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)\
    {\
        HWND thw=CreateWindowEx(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l);\
        SendMessage(thw, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), (LPARAM)true);\
return thw;\
    }
```

And in code

```
 HWND hwnd = CrWinDef(...);
```

Comment: Macros aren't functions; they're preprocessor instructions. Try subst the macro text *verbatim* in the location where it occurs in your usage. Did you *really* want  a `return` there?

Comment: Is there a reason `CrWinDef` can't be a function?

Comment: Yes, I want to return that HWND. I know generally functions are used for returning a value, but I was really to lazy to write all data types. I did that now, but still I'm interestedto learn if something like this is possible.

Comment: why don't just use inline?

Comment: Except that you're probably on Windows, you could arrange for the macro to become an `inline` function.  Unfortunately, though, Microsoft doesn't support the old standard (C99); it only supports the quarter-century old standard (C89/C90).

Comment: I can recommend you my post here!!: [Faking functions with macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424458/how-much-is-it-possible-to-create-fake-functions-with-macros-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

`#define` blindly copy and pastes the definition wherever you reference it.

```
HWND hwnd = CrWinDef(...);
```

During the pre-processing step of compilation, the macro will expand to this

```
HWND hwnd = 
{
    HWND thw = CreateWindowEx(...);

    SendMessage(thw, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), (LPARAM)true);

    return thw;
}
```

This doesn't entirely make sense as you're "assigning the value of a new scope" to a `HWND`.

You can modify your macro to also define the `HWND` instance in the current scope instead of looking at it from the perspective of a function where you take the return value.

```
#define CrWinDef(name, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)\
    HWND name = CreateWindowEx(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l);\
    SendMessage(name, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), (LPARAM)true);\

// "hwnd" now contains the HWND instance
CrWinDef(hwnd, ...);
```

Your last option is to just create an actual function that does what you're doing in the macro, but you would need to include the respective type information in the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think what you're asking for is possible in C, but you can *sort of* make it happen by <s>ab</s>using [the comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/1530508). **What follows is not code anyone should ever actually use** and represents my stubborn attempts to fulfill the OP's original request beyond the bounds of reason.

```
#define CrWinDef(var,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)\
        (var=CreateWindowEx(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l), \
        SendMessage(var, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), (LPARAM)true), \
        var)
```

This macro takes as its first argument the name of the `HWND` variable being assigned to. Usage example is as follows:

```
HWND hwnd = CrWinDef(hwnd, ... ); //arguments a through l
```

Which expands to:

```
HWND hwnd = (hwnd = CreateWindowEx(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l),
                    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), (LPARAM)true), 
                    hwnd);
```

Note that this won't work if you don't want to assign the result to a value, so you'd really have to have two macros: `CrWinDef` and `CrWinDefRet` or something like that.

Please just use a regular function.

Answer (score 2):

If compiling with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (or some compatible compiler, like [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) you could use its [statement expr](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) language extension and code:

```
#define CrWinDef(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l) ({\
 HWND thw=CreateWindowEx(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l);\
 SendMessage(thw, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), \
            (LPARAM)true);\
 thw; })
```

then later use: `HWND hwnd = CrWinDef(`...`);` but this won't work with e.g. Microsoft compilers.

As other suggested, a `static inline` function would be cleaner and more portable. Macros are brittle, e.g. if their argument is a `i++`, because it might be substituted several times, e.g. with

```
#define SQUARE(X) ((X)*(X))
```

used with `SQUARE(i++)` -this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and might increment `i` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your CrWinDef "function" doesn't have defined return type.

Why don't you use function?

Comment: And how do I define a return type?

Comment: @Dan You can't. There's nothing to declare a return type _for_. Macros are just textual replacements.

Comment: you have to use function to be able to define return type.

Comment: Or use a GNU compiler extension, [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs).  That probably isn't an option for the OP, though.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers.have pointed out, macros cannot have return values.

But in most cases, a `static inline` function will produce the same result (function will be inlined), but with added type safety, which you don't get with macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have a #define that returns a value:

```
    #define AddOne(x) ({int _temp_; _temp_ = (x) + 1; _temp_;})
      -> returns _temp_
```

This illustrates why this can be useful:

```
    #define MaxIntNotsogood(x,y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
    c = MaxIntNotsogood(a++, b--); 
      -> expands to: c = (a++ > b-- ? a++ : b--);
      -> one of the variables gets incremented or decremented twice.
```

This works more reliably:

```
    #define MaxIntBetter(x,y) ({int _x_, _y_; _x_ = (x); _y_ = (y); _x_ > _y_ ? _x_ : _y_;})
    c = MaxIntBetter(a++, b--); 
      -> expands to: c = ({int _x_, _y_; _x_ = (a++); _y_ = (b--); _x_ > _y_ ? _x_ : _y_;});
      -> each of the variables is used only once
```

A useful define to return a swapped integer for ARM:

```
    #define SWAP32X_RV(x)   ({int32_t _temp_; __ASM volatile ("rev %0, %1" : "=r" (_temp_) : "r" (x)); _temp_;})
      -> returns a byte swapped int as a value
```